# Where can I find a collection of bad/misleading data visualizations?

Tags: reference-request, statistics

Are there any collections or blogs of bad data visualizations? I know I've seen such misleading graphics in the news or in print, made misleading either maliciously or thoughtlessly, but I usually see these as one-offs on social media. Has anyone started a collection of these to use as examples in their math/stats classes?

Comment: Check out the @graphcrimes Twitter account: https://twitter.com/graphcrimes

Answer (score 2):

Check out the book [*Spurious Correlations* by Tyler Vigen](https://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations).

Answer (score 2):

Are you interested in resources in languages other than English? Bad data visualization has no nationality.

There's a blog [SmarterPoland.pl](http://smarterpoland.pl/) (in Polish) devoted to good and bad data visualization. It runs an annual (anti-)competition for the worst data chart. [Here](http://smarterpoland.pl/index.php/2021/12/plebiscyt-na-najgorszy-wykres-roku-2021/) is the 2021 edition, along with the links to previous editions. It doesn't take (almost) any knowledge of Polish to understand how bad these charts are.